# How to put safe_html in button_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add safe_html or raw html in a `button_to` to achieve something like this:

```
<%= link_to(raw("a <strong>strong</strong> link"),{:pics => true},{ :class => 'highlight'})  %>
```

My button is like this:

```
<%= button_to ("<div class='clock'></div>Start").html_safe, { action: :start, controller: "my_controller", id: my_model.id },
        class: "btn", disabled: (my_model.is_active || !my_model.ended.nil?),
        data: { "hx-post" => my_model_start_path(my_model.id), "hx-trigger" => "click", "hx-target" => "#my_model-block" } %>
```

```
<%= button_to raw("<div class='clock'></div>Start"), { action: :start, controller: "my_controller", id: my_model.id },
        class: "btn", disabled: (my_model.is_active || !my_model.ended.nil?),
        data: { "hx-post" => my_model_start_path(my_model.id), "hx-trigger" => "click", "hx-target" => "#my_model-block" } %>
```

Neither of the above codes worked. Is there a way to add html as safe string in my button_to form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip all the `.html_safe` and `.raw` stuff by passing in a block to `button_to`.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

My code below may not be 100% correct but should give you an idea how to write it.

```
<%= button_to nil, { 
    action: :start, 
    controller: "my_controller", 
    id: my_model.id, 
    class: "btn", disabled: (my_model.is_active || !my_model.ended.nil?),
    data: { 
        "hx-post" => my_model_start_path(my_model.id), 
        "hx-trigger" => "click", 
        "hx-target" => "#my_model-block" }} do %>
  <div class='clock'></div>Start
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon the below answer of @tywhang I tried and I got an interesting result.

What I wanted to generate is this:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/some_model/end/6def4c28-3d-adcb-38804e33ec95?locale=en">
    <input class="btn" disabled="disabled" data-hx-post="/some_model/end/6def4c28-f8104e33ec95?locale=en" data-hx-trigger="click" data-hx-target="#rental-block" type="submit" value="Start">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="cdawUeCFdaIBdawdaQ==">
</form>
```

With `value="Start"` to have some html instead of "Start",

And what the above code generated is this:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/en/some_model/165634c-877c-6900123-123123-1d1fc307e">
    <button action="stop" controller="some_model" id="6def4c28-f811-42adwa-31231fa-1233ec95" type="submit">
        <div class='clock'></div>Start
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="VXsdaiFwdaUQawd=aw=">
</form>
```

Apparently I lost all the data arrtibutes

(this was too long for a comment)

Comment: Fix by moving `data` attributes into `{ action: :start, controller: "my_controller", id: my_model.id, data: {...} }`